# How to load multiple data from database

Tags: java, database

I use select2 ( ) to insert data into table_a in database, so the data will look like this (D-02,D-03), unfortunately, the data not display in when i try to update the form. can anyone help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: We are not mind readers.  Explain your situation in some detail and ask a specific question. So far it's gibberish.

Comment: what do you mean by saying " I use slecet2() to insert data into table_a?!!!!!!!!!!